# Query with aggregation performance in elastic search with different orders?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation

I've one requirement say i have set of documents specific to different configurations, i need to return the latest configurations based on configVersion. but i have additional query parameters that also needs to be matched. which one of the below will be faster interms of performance in that scenario.

1) List the latest configurations based on configVersion using aggregate first, and then apply queries to fetch.
2) Apply queries first to get the matching records and then apply aggregations.

Option 1:

```
{
  "size": 10000,

    "aggs": {
    "finalFilter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "configName",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "configVersion": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                   "configName": "configuration1"
                }

            },
            {
              "term": {
                "Application": "Google"
              }
            },

            {
              "term": {
                "platform": "windows"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "ApplicationVersion": "1.1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "country": "uk"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2:

{
  "size": 10000,


  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                   "configName": "configuration1"
                }

            },
            {
              "term": {
                "Application": "Google"
              }
            },

            {
              "term": {
                "platform": "windows"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "ApplicationVersion": "1.1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "country": "uk"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "finalFilter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "configName",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "configVersion": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Thanks
Sushma

Comment: your queries look identical but the **aggs** appears after the **query** in the second example - or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, they are identical actually the query+aggregations are taking more time in execution, so i am trying to find the optimized query for it. So aggregations+query or query+aggregations will give better results is my doubt.

Comment: It won't make any difference -Elasticsearch will run the query / filter first and then do the aggregation. it doesn't matter if you put the aggs before or after the query.